# Brent's cycle detection algorithm

Tags: algorithm, primes

Can anyone please help me out with Brent's cycle detection algorithm .  I m not understanding exactly why "search for the smallest power of two 2^i that is larger than both λ and μ" ? How powers of 2 are playing role in the detection of cycle . Is it somehow related to Floyd's cycle detection algorithm ? I m unable to get it from the basics . Please help !

Comment: @WillNess What does this have to do with primes? I think the primes tag should be removed.

Comment: @gsingh2011 it's used in prime factorization algorithm. maybe prime-factorization tag should be added/replace the primes... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This method uses increasing steps (1, 2, 4, 8...) to get inside the loop as soon as possible. When P = 2^k becomes larger than both λ and μ, then tortoise (T) is in the loop, and hare (H) makes no more than P steps to meet (standing) tortoise again. It seems that some simulation would be useful. Let's we have list 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-3

```
P=1 T=0 H=0; H makes 1 step and doesn't meet T
P=2 T=1 H=1; H makes 2 steps and doesn't meet T
P=4 T=3 H=3; H makes 4 steps and doesn't meet T 
P=8 T=7 H=7; H makes 5 steps and meets T !!!!!
```

Notice: With P=4 T is inside the loop, but hare doesn't go through the whole cycle (P >= μ but P < λ )

So we have found  μ<8 and λ=5. Then we want to find μ (loop entry point)

```
T=0 H=0; H makes 5 steps; H=5 
while T <> H 
   move both
T=1 H=6
T=2 H=7
T=3 H=3 !!!!!!!
```

We've just found μ=3

Comment: Can you explain why "powers of two" is used here? If we aim to get hare inside the loop as soon as possible, why not we use "powers of 3" or "powers of 5"? If "powers of 5" is used, will this algorithm still be valid? Finally, why λ is equal to the number of last steps hare made before meeting turtle? What proof do we have to take that number as the length of cycle?  Thank you.

Comment: @carawan, I guess power-of-3 and power-of-5 also work though I have no proof. I did run some simple tests. <br/>
If the slower iterator doesn't move at all, then the algorithm is broken because the slower iterator could be outside the loop. <br/>
If the slower iterator tailgates the faster iterator and the following distance is always always below a fixed limit (like 99), then the algorithm is broken because the loop size could exceed 99. <br/> 
If the following distance grows gradually, AND the follower does move, then I think eventually they will meet.